# How to integrate support for Autopaging Plugins

Tags: php, javascript

How do I make my website compatible with all those autopaging plugins out there that load the next page beneath the current, thereby saving a page reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's depend on how you design your page.

Let's take a look at twitter page. The items there displayed in a `li`, top to down. Implementing a autopaging to page like this will be quite simple.

1. When page load, display a predefined number of item in list (10 or 20, or else)
2. When user reach the end of list, (maybe detect the position of certain element, or else), load the next page via AJAX. The back end page should detect AJAX request and then only return a portion of page that contain the list item only
3. In AJAX response handler block, do a DOM manipulation to add the newly received list item into the end of existing list.

In my project, I create function like this by myself. I'm using jQuery btw.

Comment: This is another facet that you have added to my concepts, which has rather altered my thinking on autopaging :). Now another doubt arises, How do I detect when the user has scrolled down to a certain level?? How to do this in jQuery??

Comment: Well, in my application, I use the jquery-tools scrollable (http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/index.html), so I can detect the last page easily. If your page is like twitter, maybe it not wise to have auto paging, since the visitor will never be able to see the footer. Having the items enclosed in a scrollable container is an appropriate place to do this, since it will not extend the page, and you can detect last page easily. Thare also several add-ons in Firefox & Google Chrome add autopaging to any website.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it compatible with all plugins. You can make it compatible with a specific plugin. How to do that is probably described in the documentation for said plugin.